# How to update a CSV file whenever an Excel cell value changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, csv

I have an Excel file that is linked to an application that updates the file a few times per minute. I would like to save the Excel contents (22 rows of 5 columns) to a CSV file whenever the contents of a specific cell (B22) changes.  It will overwrite the existing CSV file each time it updates, so that the CSV always represents the latest content of the Excel file.
I'm a beginner in VBA so any guidance on how to write a macro to do this would be welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that the code you want to export as CSV is documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37038399/185851).

All you need to do is call it from a function which changes whenever the worksheet changes (which just so happens to be called `Worksheet_Change`) and then check for the change being B22.

Putting both together gives you the following code:

```
' Worksheet_Change
' Called whenever a change is made to a cell in a worksheet

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Check if cell B22 has been changed 
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B22"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        ' It has changed
        Call ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV
    End If

End Sub

' ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV
' Saves the contents of Sheet1 to a CSV file in c:\tmp\test.csv
' If the file already exists, it will be silently overwritten

Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()

    Dim wbkExport As Workbook
    Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

    Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")     'Sheet to export as CSV
    Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
    shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False                       'Possibly overwrite without asking
    wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\tmp\test.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

It's worth noting that the sheet name (`Sheet1`) and the filename (`C:\tmp\test.csv`) are hard-coded. If I had written this, I would probably pass both of these as variables into `ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, Richard. I did a small test on this. I added the VBA code to the Excel file and saved it as a macro-enabled Excel file.  If I run the macro using ALT+F8, then it writes an update to the CSV, but if there’s a change to cell B22, it doesn’t update the CSV until I run the macro again. I assumed it would be running permanently in the background as long as the macro-enabled Excel file was open and being updated. Do I need to do something else to achieve the automatic updates to the CSV?

Comment: I managed to get it working.  The only problem is that if the CSV is opened by another program, then it causes a run-time error 1004 on the Excel sheet saying that you cannot save the workbook with the same name as an open workbook.  Any way around that, so that I can read the CSV in the other program without disrupting the updates?

Comment: @DWT818 It's a fairly brutal approach but try putting `On Error Resume Next` on the line before `wbkExport.SaveAs` and `On Error Goto 0` on the line after `wbkExport.Close`. If there is any error trying to save the file, it'll just ignore it. Bear in mind that if that happens then your changes that time won't be saved until the next time you edit cell B22.

Comment: Richard, thanks for the suggestion. It did indeed suppress the error messages but it also seemed to ignore updates in cell B22. However, I managed to find a solution by adding a FileCopy to generate another CSV with a different name, and my program can access that file without disrupting the Excel updates.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: As an additional question, how would I need to change the Private Sub in the above example to generate the CSV file if cell B22 is changed by a formula rather then by a user. I understand that I have to use Worksheet_Calculate instead of Worksheet_Change, but when I do that, then the Public Sub generates multiple copy CSV workbooks rather than overwriting the CSV.

Comment: @DWT818 I'd have to have a play and come back to you. To be perfectly honest, you will get a much quicker (and possibly better) answer if you submit it as a new question.